# FromBody with a "empty" values return null Model (Guid and Enum)

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm having a problem to validate certain types of values in my model (using fluent validation and FromBody).

I have this model:

```
public class PostAcess
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public List<PostAcessModule> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

That I'm passing as a parameter in my POST method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] PostAcess postAcess)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return CustomResponseFail(ModelState);

        ViewAcess result = await acessService.GetByUserId(postAcess.userId);
    ...
    }
```

In Swagger when I make a Post, with this values (UserId empty):

> {
> "UserId": "",
> "Modules": [
> {
> "id": "",
> "read": true,
> "insert": true,
> "update": true,
> "exclude": true
> }
> ]
> }

and debbuging my API, my Model (object parameter) always comes Null in my Controller, so my Model values can't get be validated by my Fluent Validator class. (Throwing a ModelState Invalid).

The same happens when I try to pass a Enum string that didn't exists in my Enum:

Enum:

```
public enum Status
{
    Active = 1,
    Inactive,
    Excluded
}
```

When I pass status string as a different value that was spected my Model (object parameter) in the Controller comes null.

> {
> "name": "string",
> "status": "Test"
> }

Validators: Unity

```
public class PostUnityValidator : AbstractValidator<PostUnity>{
private readonly IUnityRepository unityRepository;
private readonly IMapper mapper;

public Post(IUnityRepository unityRepository,
                            IMapper mapper)
{
    this.unityRepository = unityRepository;
    this.mapper = mapper;

    RuleFor(x => x.Name)
     .NotNull()
     .WithMessage("Name can't be null")

     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage("Name can't be empty");

    RuleFor(x => x.Status)
     .NotNull()
     .WithMessage("Status can't be null")

     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage("Status can't be empty")

     .IsInEnum()
     .WithMessage("Status value doesn't exists");
}}
```

PostAcess:

```
public class PostAcessValidator : AbstractValidator<PostAcess>{
private readonly IModuleRepository moduleRepository;
private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

public PostAcessValidator(IModuleRepository moduleRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    this.moduleRepository = moduleRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;

    RuleFor(x => x.UserId)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("ID can't be null")

       .NotEmpty()
       .WithMessage("ID can't be empty")

       .MustAsync(async (userId, cancelar) =>
       {
           return await UserExists(userId);
       }).WithMessage("User doesn't exists");

    RuleForEach(x => x.Modules).SetValidator(new PostAcessModuleValidator(moduleRepository));
}

private async Task<bool> UserExists(Guid userId)
{
    return await userRepository.UserExists(userId);
}}
```

PostAcessModule:

```
public class PostAcessModuleValidator : AbstractValidator<PostAcessModule>{
private readonly IModuleRepository moduleRepository;

public PostAcessModuleValidator(IModuleRepository moduleRepository)
{
    this.moduleRepository = moduleRepository;

    RuleFor(x => x.Id)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("ID can't be null")

       .NotEmpty()
       .WithMessage("ID can't be empty")

        .MustAsync(async (moduleId, cancelar) =>
        {
            return await ModuleExists(moduleId);
        }).WithMessage("Module doesn't exists");

    RuleFor(x => x.Read)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("The value can't be null");

    RuleFor(x => x.Post)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("The value can't be null");

    RuleFor(x => x.Put)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("The value can't be null");

    RuleFor(x => x.Exclude)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("The value can't be null");
}

private async Task<bool> ModuleExists(Guid moduleId)
{
    return await moduleRepository.ModuleExists(moduleId);
}}
```

I would like to catch that cases to return a message that "UserId can't be empty" or "Enum value not found".

(When I use FromForm it works but I need to user FromBody or something like that).

If someone could help me, I'll be really thankfull!

Comment: You stated that you are using FluentValidation, can you share the related validators code?

Comment: ASP.NET binding mechanism will fill non-nullable struct properties with default values ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#no-source-for-a-model-property)), that is empty GUID for `Guid` type or 0 for enum, which in your case is not a valid enum member.

Comment: To avoid that, you can use `NotEmpty()` rule ([docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#notempty-validator)), but keep in mind that if your logic allows default values, adding `NotEmpty()` for a property of non-nullable struct type will block models having default values. If that is not the case, consider defining models using nullable types for structs, then `NotEmpty()` will safeguard you from missing properties being `null` as well.

Comment: From the time that i wrote this post, i solved the problem with GUID(I set in my model to recive null objects ? and it works), but enums i still have the same problem.

To the first comment I edited the post.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share code for `PostAcess` and `PostAcessModule` validators?

Comment: Of course! I edited the post with the validators.

Comment: Looking at it now, no exceptional remark comes to my mind except the one I already wrote, that you should try using nullable types for struct and enum properties. Only then those `NotNull()` rules declared for e.g. `Guid` type property make sense. If that still doesn't work for you, you can include a testing data set for which you would like to have a working solution, but currently you don't have.

Comment: I tried to use ? in my enum end didn't work, how should I do to make it a nullable type? Can you give me an exemple please? Thanks!